# DataType<cv::detail::deriv_type>::depth what is it used for

Tags: opencv

I was wondering why this line is used for in the lucas kanade tracker in opencv:

`DataType<cv::detail::deriv_type>::depth`

can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV, the depth of a `Mat` refers to the type of data contained in the `Mat`'s data buffer. They are represented by integer values which correspond to a given data type. These integers are most commonly abstracted by an appropriate macro definition (e.g. `uchar` data is represented by the macro `CV_8U`).

`cv::DataType` is a type-traits class that provides a method to obtain the corresponding integer value without having to memorize which macro means which data type. There are very few cases where user code needs to use `DataType::depth`. Much more common is `DataType::type`.

A simple example shows one possible use of `DataType::depth`:

```
cv::Mat uchar_data = cv::Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat float_data;
uchar_data.convertTo(float_data, cv::DataType<float>::depth);
                              // ^^ This could equivalently be replaced
                              //    by CV_32F macro
float_data.at<float>(0,1) += 0.5f;
std::cout << float_data << std::endl;
```